# Testing angular controller with many dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-runner

I've started testing my Angular app and have question that bother me a lot. For example I have controller (mainController) which is injecting 2 services: authService, configService.

Before testing I should prepare something like that:

```
describe('controller: testController with testService mock', function() {      
    var controller, authService, configService;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _authService_, _configService_) {         
        authService = _authService_;
        configService = _configService_;

        controller = $controller('mainController');
    }));    

    it('should be registered with all dependencies', function() {
        expect(controller).to.be.defined;

        expect(authService).to.be.defined;
        expect(configService).to.be.defined;
    });

}
```

And that's totally clear for me. What if one of services or both have their own dependencies (services) ? Of course I'm gonna add it by passing through the inject function. In small apps that's no big problem. I'm adding as much services as I need. But the question is what if that services are injecting other services and others injecting others and there is a huge hierarchy ? What if we must add 30 services and we can't make a mistake because otherwise it's not gonna work ?

To be honest I've search a lot but there are many testing examples and tutorials but every single one is based on totally basic apps with few controllers and services.

Is there a painless way to handle this ? Maybe there is a way to skip some dependencies or force to automatically inject services with it's dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

> What if one of services or both have their own dependencies (services) ? Of course I'm gonna add it by passing through the inject function

No, you won't. Angular will instantiate these services and inject them where they need to be injected, provided they're in the 'app' module or in one of its dependencies.

There's no reason to inject any service into your test, unless you need to do something with them, like calling one of their methods, or spying them.

Comment: Ok but if i don't do that, I've got error "before each hook FAILED". What's wrong ?

Comment: When you ask about an error, post the code causing the error in the question, as well as the complete error message and stack trace you get.